# Powershell replacing part of field returned from Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I'm extracting fields from Active Directory and piping that into a .csv file, My Select-Object command returns the fields by name. My problem is some of these fields contain carriage return and line feed information I want to remove *before* piping it into the .csv

Example:

```
Select-Object SamAccountName,displayName,info | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | 
Out-File -Append -FilePath $Filepath -Encoding unicode
```

How can I intercept and amend the 'info' field before firing it to .csv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove carriage return and line feed using regex. Try next snippet:

```
Select-Object -property SamAccountName, DisplayName, Info |
    % {
        $_.SamAccountName = [regex]::Replace($_.SamAccountName, "(`n|`r)+"," ", "Multiline");
        $_.DisplayName= [regex]::Replace($_.DisplayName, "(`n|`r)+"," ", "Multiline");
        $_.Info = [regex]::Replace($_.Info, "(`n|`r)+"," ", "Multiline");
        return $_;
    } | 
    ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | 
    Out-File -Append -FilePath $Filepath -Encoding unicode
```

Comment: Hi Akim, thanks for the response.Not sure what's going on there but I now get ÿþ as an output, just once - that's the new content of the entire document rather than the 3k lines expected.

Comment: sorry, i'd forget to add `return $_;`. Try snippet now

Comment: I still receive the same output. No worries though I've resorted to adding a line to manipulate the finished file to remove the information I needed to. Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the output using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject):

```
Select-Object SamAccountName,displayName,{$_.info.replace("`r", "").replace("`n", "")} 
    | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation 
    | Out-File -Append -FilePath $Filepath -Encoding unicode
```

The backtick ` allows you to insert [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.2) `r is carriage return and `n is new line.